# how to plot dataframe column by category

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have data set from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv)

I added another column with name Summary.

I'm trying to plot which x=date and y=summary **But** every country have a separate line.

```
    
new_df = df["Country"].isin(["Germany","Canada","United Kingdom","US","France","China","India"])
new_df = df[new_df]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)


col_list = ['Confirmed','Recovered','Deaths']
new_df["Summary"] = new_df[col_list].sum(axis=1)

new_df['Date'] = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
print(new_df.tail())

            Date         Country  Confirmed  Recovered  Deaths  Summary
91811 2021-05-30  United Kingdom    4499937      15486  128043  4643466
91812 2021-05-31  United Kingdom    4503231      15507  128045  4646783
91813 2021-06-01  United Kingdom    4506333      15508  128045  4649886
91814 2021-06-02  United Kingdom    4510597      15514  128057  4654168
91815 2021-06-03  United Kingdom    4515778      15517  128075  4659370
```

I want to plot something like this (line for the growth of every country in a different line)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import Seaborn `import seaborn as sns` and plot it with Seaborn:

```
sns.lineplot(data=new_df, x="Date", y="Summary", hue="Country")
```

[image]

To get only the dates from 2021, you need to modify the dataframe like this:

```
new_df = new_df[pd.DatetimeIndex(new_df["Date"]).year >= 2021]
```

Comment: this also give for days from 2020 , I wanted for only in 2021.
do you have any clue how to do it ?